problema de refresco
realice un sistema en react, el mismo de forma local me permite iniciar sesión con las credenciales si estas están correctas pasando a la verificación por código y si este es correcto permite ingresar a la primera vista, en la misma puedo navegar sin problema y además, puedo refrescar la pagina y esta permanece en la misma. Pero al momento de ejecutar el comando npm run build y subir dicho archivo a raiway este me permite seguir los pasos anteriormente expuestos, pero si intento refrescar la pagina se me muestra el siguiente error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () , me podrian ayudar a resolverlo

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
